# operator precedence with complex numbers

Tags: python, cmath

This should be self-explanatory

```
>>> (1+2j).real  #Normal Usage
1.0
>>> (1+2j).imag  #Normal Usage
2.0
>>> 1+2j.real  #Normal Usage
1.0
>>> 1+2j.imag  #Flips Out
3.0
>>> 123+657j.real
123.0
>>> 123+657j.imag
780.0
```

`z.imag` somehow adds up the real and imaginary parts.
I found this interesting .. is this a bug or is this an intentional feature?

Comment: its 1 + (2j.imag) = 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `1+2j.imag` is being parsed as `1+(2j.imag)`. Clearly `2j.imag` is `2.0`, so `1+2j` returns `3.0`. When you do `1+2j.real`, Python adds `1` and `2j.real`. `2j.real` is `0.0`, so you get the correct answer `1.0` in return.

If you parenthesize the complex number, like in your first two examples, you will get the expected results.

Comment: `1+2j.real` is also parsed as `1+(2j.real)`, with the second summand equal to zero.

Comment: @liori yeah, I was just getting to that part.

Comment: Cool .. thanks. I find this answer highly interesting for some reason :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an operator precedence issue. `.` has higher precedence than `+`, so you are effectively doing

```
1+(2j.imag)
```

which of course is 3.

It is a Very Good Idea™ to always parenthesize complex number literals.

Answer (score 2):

No madness there, really. Here's what happens: the '.' operator has precedence over the +, that's all. That means

```
>>> 1+2j.imag
```

is evaluated as 1 + (2j.imag) which is 1 + 2 which is 3. The same is valid for the other examples.